# Strange issue with .docx files using OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, onedrive

I have really strange and irritating issue using Microsoft Office and OneDrive on my Windows 8.1 machine. Current version of Office is 2016, but same issue was also on Office 2013.

For example, I have file named "`clientdata.docx`", and then other files shows up in my OneDrive synced folder, like this, where machine name is repeated in every file name:

```
clientdata-Users-Laptop.docx
clientdata-Users-Laptop-Users-Laptop.docx
clientdata-Users-Laptop-Users-Laptop-Users-Laptop.docx
```

Where obviously, "Users-Laptop" is user PC name. Why is this happening, how can I prevent it, and what it means?

NOTE: I have another computer, from which I am connecting to this machine with this issue, and I also can see those file, but I can open only last one, other are marked with grey X sign. maybe is this somehow related.

Comment: I use both of those versions of Office daily, sync files to OneDrive daily, this isn't normal behavior this happens to all files?

Comment: @Ramhound, it seems that this happening only to files that are or have been edited.